# Creating a symptom checker on Dialogflow

Tags: bots, dialogflow-es, chatbot

Can a symptom checker, such as WebMd's be created in Dialogflow. Can dialog flow connect different user inputs (symptoms) to one output (disease) or do i need to use a different kind of framework for this?

Answer (score 3):

Dialogflow is designed to help you understand *what* a user is saying - not what the replies should be. So you can use Dialogflow to capture the symptoms and hand them off to your code, which handles the logic and returns a conclusion.